# How to make edit button work in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and I am creating an app, where I have to edit a text. I have created the button. But, I need some help to set up the edit button. When the user clicks on the edit button, I want them to edit the text.

> Here is my edit button

```
<a class="back" href="#/people">Back</a>

   <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</button>
</td>

 <div class="people-view">
 <h2 class="name">{{people.name}}</h2>
 <span class="title">{{people.title}}</span>
 <span class="date">{{people.date}} </span>



  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maintain a variable `edit` which you can make `true` on-clicking **edit** button
depending on that variable toggle the **text** and **input**

```
 <a class="back" href="#/lawyer">Back</a>

       <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit=ture">Edit</button>
    </td>

     <div class="people-view">
     <h2 class="name"><span ng-show="!edit">{{people.name}}</span><input ng-show="edit" value="{{people.name}}"></h2>
     <span class="title"><span ng-show="!edit">{{people.title}}<input ng-show="edit" value="{{people.title}}"></span></span>
     <span class="date"><span ng-show="!edit">{{people.date}} <input ng-show="edit" value="{{people.date}}"></span></span>



      </div>
```

**[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/c1gw0rr9/1/)**

Comment: wait i'll create a fiddle demo

Comment: @John  give ng-model to inputs and put  one submit button on submit of this button call a function, get the model values there

Comment: can you please show me in the code for the update button?